# A Geometry Based proof

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

> ABC is an isosceles triangle with AB=AC. M is the mid point of BC and O is the point on the line AM such that OB is perpendicular to AB. Q is arbitrary point on BC. E lies on AB and F lies on the line AC such that E,Q and F are collinear

Prove that -

1- EF perpendicular to OQ if QE=QF

2- QE=QF if OQ perpendicular to EF

I am confused where to start. Also what is the meaning of 'Arbitary Points'? I have only managed to draw the figure. Am I correct or am I leaving out something?[image: my attempt]

Comment: What did you try?  Write something about your work.

Comment: i am unable to solve it, only the diagram i have drawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\implies $

Let $QE=FQ$ then prove $OQ\perp EF$

in $\triangle EBQ$, $\dfrac{QE}{\sin\angle ABC}=\dfrac{BE}{\sin\angle BQE} $

in $\triangle CQF$, $\dfrac{QF}{\sin\angle QCF}=\dfrac{CF}{\sin\angle CQF}=\dfrac{QF}{\sin\angle (180-ACB)}=\dfrac{QF}{\sin\angle ACB}$

$\sin(180-\alpha)=\sin\alpha$,

$\angle ABC =\angle ACB$,($\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.),

$\angle BQE =\angle CQF$,(vertcally opposite angles)

Since $QE=FQ$, then $\dfrac{BE}{\sin\angle BQE}=\dfrac{CF}{\sin\angle CQF}$

Hence, $BE=CF$.

Now

$OB=OC$

$\angle B=\angle C=90$

$BE=CF$, (proven)

$\triangle OBE \cong \triangle OCF$, (S.A.S)

Therefore $OE=OF$,  $\triangle OEF$ is isosceles

Since $QE=FQ$, then $OQ\perp EF$

$\Longleftarrow$

Let $OQ\perp EF$,  then show, $QE=FQ$

$\ angle OEQ=\angle OBQ$,($OBEQ$ is cyclic quadrilateral, $\angle B+\angle\ Q=180$

$\ angle OFQ=\angle OCQ$,($OFCQ$ is cyclic quadrilateral, $\angle C =\angle\ Q$

Hence,

$\triangle EOF$ is an isosceles and $QE=FQ$

Comment: Thanks, I never thought that the concept of cyclic quadrilaterals can help me to solve it.

Comment: You are welcome